# Is there any way to reuse a coroutines's channel values

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I wonder if there is any solution to reuse a channel's elements after they've been consumed. for example, irritating through channel 2 times.

I've tried this:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    //sampleStart
    val channel = Channel<String>(2)

    println(channel.isEmpty)  // true

    channel.send("foo")
    channel.send("bar")

    channel.close()

    println(channel.isEmpty) // false

    for (it in channel) println(it) // foo, bar

    println(channel.isEmpty) // false!!!

    for (it in channel) println("item: $it")
}
```

the strange thing here is `channel.isEmpty` returns `false` after all the values have been consumed.

Comment: regarding `isEmpty` Kiskae (or the documentation) already states it... regarding reuse of the channel... maybe you want to use a [broadcast channel](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/reactive/coroutines-guide-reactive.md#rx-subject-vs-broadcastchannel) instead? Or are [flows](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/) what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies in the documentation of [`ReceiveChannel#isEmpty`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-receive-channel/is-empty.html):

> Returns true if the channel is empty (contains no elements) and the receive attempt will suspend. This function returns false for isClosedForReceive channel.